# UTF-8 characters causing problems with web-to-case form

Tags: web2case

I have a web-to-case form that works, but if a field has text pasted into it (for example, from an email) and the text contains certain characters, the case doesn't get created.

For example, one of those characters is a "dash" that is not the ASCII dash, but it encodes as a %96, which is an "en dash" symbol. When that is in a field, and it is submitted, the case does not get created. If I replace that with a ASCII hyphen, it creates the case.

What is Salesforce checking for when disallowing characters? Is it anything above %7f?

Comment: Salesforce itself uses UTF-8, so that shouldn't be the issue. What status code are you getting from Salesforce when you submit your form with an en-dash? Do you have any validation rules within Salesforce on the `Case` object that have something like `NOT(REGEX(^[a-zA-z0-9]$))`? If you're getting Http 200 from the form submission, then you'd likely need to capture (and inspect) an execution log for the "running user" (which is probably something like the "Automated Process User")

Comment: I don't get any error status back from Salesforce. It looks like the form posts and it redirects to the URL it is supposed to redirect to. I look at the payload in Chrome and all the fields are there. In my web form, if a field has the "em dash" character (%96) and I submit it, the case doesn't get created. I remove it or replace it with a regular ASCII hyphen and it creates the case. And I've tried that in multiple fields. Very odd.

Comment: Please read my first comment again. The http status code isn't necessarily an error code, and that distinction is important. You'll need to open the developer tools in your browser and get to the network tab before attempting to submit the form. Then look for the network request to Salesforce (domain column) and look for the number in the status column. If you see `200` in the status column, then you need to look within Salesforce. A `500` status would mean you probably have a validation rule (in Salesforce) that's causing the issue.

Comment: Yes, I do know that about http status codes. It is a 200 - I was referring to that as not being an "error", meaning the form was accepted.